# How do i update a date field of a user when the admin form is saved?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have built a django application that is used to store the notes of a meeting. The studio note object is called `StudioMeetingNote` and it has 2 foreign key fields with the `CustomUser` model, namely `secretary` and `chairman`. Each `CustomUser` instance has 2 `date` fields namely `last_date_chairman` and `last_date_secretary`. When a user is assigned chairman in the `StudioMeetingNote` form I want the `last_date_chairman` field of this user to get the same value as the date assigned to the field `meeting_start_date` field that belongs to the `StudioMeetingNote` itself. The same goes for `last_date_secretary`.

I decided to use the `def save_model` method for this. It resides in the `StudioMeetingNoteAdmin` class that represents the `StudioMeetingNote` class in the admin section. The entire implementation looks like this:

```
class StudioMeetingNoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

fields = (('meeting_start_time', 'meeting_end_time'), ('chairman', 'secretary'), 'absent_persons',)

# fieldsets = [
#     ('Tijden', {'fields': ['meeting_start_time', 'meeting_end_time']}),
#     ('Wie is de voorzitter/notulist', {'fields': [('chairman', 'secretary')]}),
#     ('Opkomst', {'fields': [('attending_persons', 'absent_persons')]}),
# ]
inlines = [OpeningAndParticularitiesInline, ActionListPointInline, RemarksPriorMeetingInline, IssuesToAddressInline, OurNextMoveInline, QuestionRoundInline]
list_filter = ['meeting_start_time']
search_fields = ['meeting_start_time']
list_display = ('meeting_start_time', 'chairman', 'secretary')
save_as = True

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    save_user = False
    if 'chairman' in form.changed_data:
        obj.chairman = form.cleaned_data['chairman']
        obj.chairman.last_date_chairman = form.cleaned_data.get('meeting_start_date')
        save_user = True
    if 'secretary' in form.changed_data:
        obj.secretary = form.cleaned_data['secretary']
        obj.secretary.last_date_secretary = form.cleaned_data.get('meeting_end_date')
        save_user = True
    if save_user:
        obj.save()
```

The `studio note` save correctly, but when i look whether the user assigned secretary/chairman has got his secretary/chairman date updated i can see that no update has happened. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my `save_model` code?

Thank you

EDIT: Here is the full models.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
import pytz

# class MusicGroup(models.Model):
#     name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
from users.models import CustomUser


class StudioMeetingNote(models.Model):
    chairman = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='chairman', verbose_name='Voorzitter')
    secretary = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='secretary', verbose_name='Notulist')
    attending_persons = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name='attending_persons', verbose_name='Aanwezig')
    absent_persons = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name='absent_persons', verbose_name='Afwezig', blank=True)
    meeting_start_time = models.DateTimeField('Start tijd')
    meeting_end_time = models.DateTimeField('Eind tijd')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.meeting_start_time
                   .astimezone(pytz.timezone('CET'))
                   .date())

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = 'Studio overleg notitie'
    # def __str__(self):
    #     return 'Studio overleg notitie'



class ActionListPoint(models.Model):
    studio_meeting = models.ForeignKey(StudioMeetingNote, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='studio_meeting_action_list', verbose_name='Studio overleg')
    who = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='who', verbose_name='Wie')
    what = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Wat', blank=True)
    when = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Wanneer', blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Status', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = 'Actie punten lijst'


class OpeningAndParticularities(models.Model):
    studio_meeting = models.ForeignKey(StudioMeetingNote, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='studio_meeting_opening_particularities', verbose_name='Studio overleg')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='added_by_p_and_p', verbose_name='Toegevoegd door')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150000, verbose_name="Inhoud")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = 'Opening en bijzondheden'


class RemarksPriorMeeting(models.Model):
    studio_meeting = models.ForeignKey(StudioMeetingNote, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='studio_meeting_remarks_prior_meeting', verbose_name='Studio overleg')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='added_by_remarks_prior', verbose_name='Toegevoegd door')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150000, verbose_name="Inhoud")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = 'Opmerkingen over vorige notulen'


class IssuesToAddress(models.Model):
    studio_meeting = models.ForeignKey(StudioMeetingNote, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='studio_meeting_issues_to_address', verbose_name='Studio overleg')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='added_by_issues_to_address', verbose_name='Toegevoegd door')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150000, verbose_name="Inhoud")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = 'Binnengekomen punten'


class OurNextMove(models.Model):
    studio_meeting = models.ForeignKey(StudioMeetingNote, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='studio_meeting_our_next_move', verbose_name='Studio overleg')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='added_by_our_next_move', verbose_name='Toegevoegd door')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150000, verbose_name="Inhoud")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = 'Wij zijn aan zet'

class QuestionRound(models.Model):
    studio_meeting = models.ForeignKey(StudioMeetingNote, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='studio_meeting_question_round', verbose_name='Studio overleg')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='added_by_question_round', verbose_name='Toegevoegd door')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150000, verbose_name="Inhoud")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = 'Rondvraag'
```

Comment: Hi, @FAM_Maurice. Could you please provide your models.py in a way I could reproduce it here?

Comment: @Eliakin Costa i've added it just now